# How to Ionic autocompile

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have first try Ionic Framework , but i have a problem . When i have saving the new code, compiler in ionic is not working for auto compile. Then, i must disconnect ionic serve and retry ionic serve again. I use Ionic version 4.
In my friend, Ionic can auto compile.

This is my Screnshoot when i have saving new code.
[image]

Please help my problem, because This is very difficult when I make new changes.

Comment: Can you tell me command do you use to build ionic app and run on device?

Comment: to build I use `Ionic start myApp blank` , to run I use `ionic serve`

Answer (score 0):

Although ionic has a live reload feature i.e. the code rebuilds and application reloads when there is a change in code. However it does not work sometimes. Have a look at [this thread](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/49700270-bug-ionic-serve-live-reload-is-not-working) and see if you can find a solution.

I use `ion cordova run ios -l` to build and run my application on and ios device. And live reload works perfectly. If you cant get `ionic server` to work, try using `ion cordova run ios -l` or `ion cordova run android -l` depending on which device you are testing your app on. The `-l` flag is for live reaload i.e. it rebuilds and reloads app on your device. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Work for me**

Remove the folder `node_modules` and file `package-lock.json`, then at terminal run:

```
npm install --save
```